# Error When Running R CMD check: Error in running tools::texi2pdf()

Tags: r, package, latex

I am building a software package in R that I want to upload to CRAN. When I run `R CMD check <packagename>` I get this error:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
Re-running with no redirection of stdout/stderr.
Hmm ... looks like a package
Warning in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  :
  texi2dvi script/program not available, using emulation
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  pdflatex is not available
Warning in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  :
  texi2dvi script/program not available, using emulation
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  pdflatex is not available
Error in running tools::texi2pdf()
You may want to clean up by 'rm -Rf /tmp/RtmpgTVVxI/Rd2pdf3bf51332b589'
```

Can someone interpret this for me? I am developing on the latest version of Ubuntu and the latest version of R.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: It seems you do not have an installation of LaTeX available (specifically tools like `pdflatex`). You might need to verify that you something like TeXLive or TinyTeX installed, depending on your OS.

Comment: So you're saying that `pdflatex` is not an R software package that I need to install, right? Instead I need to install `pdflatex` on Ubuntu?

Comment: On systems without LaTeX installed run `R CMD check --no-manual --no-vignettes packagename_*.tar.gz` instead.  Whether or not you add `--as-cran` or test from the directory instead of the tarball.  You can of course install the LaTeX parts in Ubuntu, it is all there (but has a bit of an installation footprint so I always do on 'real' machine but not on CI as it takes extra time).

Comment: I think Dirk's suggestion to check/package without formatting the docs is a good step; if you want that, however, then consider something like `apt-get install texlive` as a start, I'm sure others can give more detailed suggestions.

Comment: Yep, I maintain the Debian (and hence Ubuntu) packages for this and there are proper `Suggests:` or `Recommends:` there.  It is a wee bit fiddly with some font packages etc.  Best discussed on the `r-sig-debian` list.

Comment: This is all extremely helpful and insightful. Thank you!